# local changes are lost when using git

Tags: git, github, version-control, bitbucket

I am using Bitbucket for versioning control. Unfortunately, I pushed my commit to wrong repository then I got

```
fatal: refusing to merge unrelated histories
```

then I applied this command before I realize it is the wrong repo.

```
git pull origin master --allow-unrelated-histories
```

now my project is missed up and I also lost my local changes which I do not have backup for.
is there any way I can restore my local changes and discard the remote origin.

Comment: Run `git reflog` to find the Sha of the commit before the accidental merge. Then do `git reset --hard that-sha` to reset to the prior state.

Comment: Before you do anything else: take a deep breath and create a backup of your local repo. Now: were your local changes committed?

Comment: thank you so much, you saved my day. I restored my changes back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First thing is, if those changes were not committed, they are probably lost. If you have committed those changes, then you can do something about it.

Run `git reflog` to see the changes that happened. You might have to scroll a bit to see your previous commit, depending on what happened during the merge. Use `git reflog --relative-date` if required.

Just make a copy of the repo before proceeding to the next step just in case.

You'll get something like this from `reflog`:

```
a190818 (HEAD -> master, origin/master, origin/HEAD) HEAD@{0}: reset: moving to HEAD
a190818 (HEAD -> master, origin/master, origin/HEAD) HEAD@{1}: pull origin master: Fast-forward
3cd9c9f HEAD@{2}: reset: moving to HEAD
3cd9c9f HEAD@{3}: pull: Fast-forward
e7467f1 HEAD@{4}: pull --tags origin master: Fast-forward
821119f HEAD@{5}: checkout: moving from 200-banks to master
821119f HEAD@{6}: checkout: moving from master to 200-banks
821119f HEAD@{7}: pull --tags origin master: Fast-forward
8913f7e HEAD@{8}: checkout: moving from blog-link-color-fix to master
```

Figure out which one of the above lines denotes your correct repo state. Let's say the third line, ie `3cd9c9f`. You then do `git reset --hard 3cd9c9f`. And the repo should be reset to that point.